# Using Exchange WebServices - EWS - in Universal App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, exchangewebservices

I'm developing an Universal App in c# - Is there a way to consume EWS in Universal Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cool thing about webservices is, that you can consume them from anything that can reach out to http. So you *can* talk to it using `HttpClient`.

As ews is a very complex api, you may look out for [the EWS managed api package](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api). They sadly [don't support .Net Core yet](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/96) (and therefore UWP Apps). But it's open source they take pull requests, so you just try to move it over to a .netstandard type of library.

So in short: Yes you can, but it's complicated...